# How can I use M/S Graph APIs to read Sharepoint lists

Tags: api, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

I see from other Users' questions that this *used* not to be possible but other research suggests it now *might* be; I'm using Graph Explorer and have started with this generic URL: [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{siteId}/lists/{listId}/](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/%7BsiteId%7D/lists/%7BlistId%7D/). I'm logged in as a User who is an Owner of the Sharepoint site I'm going after. But so far, I have not been able to find, much less see the contents of any Lists that I know are there in the site. Q1: Is this even possible (now)? Q2: How - or - what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible but the graph API doesn't rely on the permissions as defined on SharePoint and might explain why you are not seeing the lists you own via the graph api.

You will have to setup the necessary Azure AD permissions on your app to access SharePoint list and items via the graph api.

As shown below, i can read data from the specified list based on permissions already consented to.

[image]